# Redis Store doesn't have a get method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io, express

http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html mentions....
"Every session store must implement the following methods: "

1. .get(sid,callback)
2. .set(sid, session, callback)
3. .destroy(sid, callback)

I'm using the following code to attempt to get the SID:

**Node JavaScript, using Socket.io connection**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var sid = socket.id;
  if (sid) {
    sessionStore.get(sid, function (error, session) {
      console.log("Connect Sid: " + sid);
    });
  }
});
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object function RedisStore(options) {
    options = options || {};
    Store.call(this, options);
    this.client = new redis.createClient(options.port || options.socket, options.host, options);
    if (options.pass) {
      this.client.auth(options.pass, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
      });    
    }

    if (options.db) {
      var self = this;
      self.client.select(options.db);
      self.client.on("connect", function() {
        self.client.send_anyways = true;
        self.client.select(options.db);
        self.client.send_anyways = false;
      });
    }
  } has no method 'get'
```

### Inclusion of redis

```
//Redis store for storage
var sessionStore = require('connect-redis')(express); 
...
...
app.use(express.session({secret: "keyboard cat",store: new sessionStore}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from: https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

```
This means express users may do the following, since express.session.Store points to the connect.session.Store function:
```

This seems to work:

```
express.session.Store(sid, function(){ console.log("Connect Sid: " + sid); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to type `new` when you instantiated the store perhaps?

Comment: I've added the code which i've used to include, and initiate the redis store.

Comment: See - you're calling .get on the sessionStore variable, which refers to the RedisStore class, not to the instantiated store.

Comment: Try
`var sessionStore = new ( require('connect-redis')(express) );`
...
`express.session({ store: sessionStore, secret: 'keyboard cat' })`

Comment: Anyway - not the best way to write it but i guess it's gonna work with what else you've written already.

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3442/discussion-between-jack-and-hristo)

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express); 
var sessionStore = new RedisStore; 
...
app.use(express.session({secret: "keyboard cat",store: sessionStore}));
```

This way you can reference session data using the sessionStore object from socket.io code later if needed.